# File not uploading to tmp directory

Tags: coldfusion-2018

We recently upgraded to CF2018 and nothing went wrong previously with this function. However, the most recent CF patches were applied by our server guy yesterday. That may have something to do with it. We've been receiving the error related to the import of a .csv file:

```
An error occurred when performing a file operation read on file C:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp\2020-04-07.csv
```

As I understand it, file uploads are automatically stored in this temp directory until you do something with it. However, my file upload is NOT appearing there. Code below.

It's very old inherited code so unless the use of CFFORM, CFINPUT etc is relevant to this problem, I'm not worried about that right now.

**index.cfm**

```
<CFFORM name="Import_Trans_File" Action="import_trans.cfm" Method="Post">   
    <input title="Import Trans File" size="50" name="Select_File" type="file">
    <cfinput type="submit" name="Import_File" value="Import File">          
</CFFORM>
```

**import_trans.cfm** (test for existence of file)

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp" recurse="false" name="myList">
<cfdump var="#myList#"><cfabort>
```

The file is not present.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the CFFORM, CFINPUT was indeed the problem. I don't know why. But as soon as I changed it to plain old FORM (with enctype="multipart/form-data") and INPUT, my file appeared. So...